# Creating comma-separated '?' placeholders for SQL query parameters

Tags: php, array

I have come up with a code that takes the total number of an array and creates `?` for each, then separates them by a comma; leaving me a list like the one below:

```
?, ?, ?, ?, ?...
```

I am using this for my `sql` queries with prepared statements, instead of having to create the prepared statement each time, I want to just have an easily accessible class that does the heavy work.

So far I have a `for` loop code which I came up with to get the comma-separated question marks. First I create an `array` of `[0] => ? ...` based on the total number of the original array and then implode the value and add the comma between each element.

```
<?php
$arr = array(
    'name' => 'James Bond',
    'age' => 60,
    'hobbies' => 'Saving England',
    'country' => 'England',
    'language' => 'English',
    'children' => 'too many to count'
);

for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++)
{
    $question[$i] = '?';
}    
print_r( implode(', ', $question) );
// outputs: ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?
?>
```

Now my question is, is there a more efficient way of achieving this, such as a one-liner that just takes the total array number and creates the number automatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `?` array can be filled using `array_fill`:

```
implode(', ', array_fill(0, sizeof($arr), '?'))
```

Comment: That's a beautiful one-liner... Thank you very much

Answer (score 4):

Xiaoy312's suggestion is one of the common methods used to generate comma-separated placeholder strings.  It generates an array containing `?` valued elements, then joins them into a string using commas as glue.

Another common method is:

> ```
> rtrim(str_repeat('?,',sizeof($arr)),',');
> ```

or the equivalent:

```
substr(str_repeat('?,',sizeof($arr)),0,-1);
```

My above methods directly generate a string (no temporary array) then merely trims the last character (comma) off the end.

All three mentioned methods will use 3 functions and no conditionals.  All, in my opinion, are equally elegant and in all reasonable cases the performance will seem equal to the end user.

In my few simple tests on 3v4l.org, I found that the `rtrim(str_repeat(sizeof()))` method is slightly faster than Xiaoy's `implode(array_fill(),sizeof())` method and my `substr(str_repeat(sizeof())` method.

I mean you could go with: `implode(',',array_map(function(){return '?';},$arr));` but it seems less elegant and is less efficient.

`rtrim(array_reduce($arr,function($carry){return $carry.'?,';}),',');` is surprisingly efficient but like `array_map()` it is less compact/elegant than other `fill`/`repeat` methods.

I don't have any formal benchmark results to post.  Like all speed tests, the only relevant information for your project(s) is performance in your exact environment.  Always do your own benchmarks, but be careful not to waste time micro-optimizing.

---

As an aside, I would like to suggest some micro-optimizations that I use as a matter habit...

When you are writing `for` loops, always cache the `count()` by setting it to a variable in the first expression.  This will ensure that you aren't calling `count()` on every iteration.

```
for($i = 0, $count = count($arr); $i < $count; $i++)
```

When the result of pre-incrementing and post-incrementing is the same, I use pre-incrementing as the default because I read that it is ever-so-slightly faster.

```
for($i = 0, $count = count($arr); $i < $count; ++$i)
```

When you are assigning array keys starting from `0`, you can let php index the array for you.

```
$question[] = '?';
```

When you want to loop through all elements in an array, you can use `foreach()` to avoid counting the array size as well as declaring and incrementing a "counter".

```
foreach($arr as $v){
    $question[]='?';
}
```

Comment: Very good answer... Thank you very much, I appreciate the time. Your considerations are good insight.

Comment: @YourCommonSense that is an unhelpful comment.  You know you have my ear/respect, so why not say something educational?

Comment: @YourCommonSense what do you mean?

Comment: @Samuel I mean that none of these considerations are of even smallest value but rather harmful. All this rant on which method is faster do a severe harm. You should never benchmark such pointless code parts like it is suggested here. For such a trifle one-time string operation all methods are equally faster. Give it a thought and you will lose a lot of your valuable time for nothing. So just unsee it. Syntax sugar suggestions at the bottom are good, but only in terms of a nicer code, but not in terms of performance at all.

Comment: I am confident that I have nothing to apologize for in my post.  The question asked for efficient one-liners, I endeavored to provide an assortment of viable options and stated that the speed impacts will go unnoticed.  I am neither deceiving anyone nor doing any harm.  When settling in on why I consistently use certain snippets when I write code, I prefer to have a rational reason(s) -- sometimes micro-optomization breaks the tie.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Thank you, that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Given your starting array, which appears to be a field-value map, I find it odd that you want to go with question-mark-style query parameters instead of named placeholders. You might find named placeholders more useful should you ever need to do some debugging around your queries.

This can also simplify your SQL preparation. For example, one might typically build field and/or parameter strings directly from an input array like you have shown.

You can then also work directly with such an array when executing the prepared statement.

For example in PDO:

```
$paramArray = [];
foreach($inputArray as $key => $value) {
    $paramArray[':' . $key] = $value;
}
$fieldString = '`' . implode('`,`' array_keys($inputArray)) . '`';
$paramString = implode(',', array_keys($paramArray));
$sql = "
    INSERT INTO
    table ({$fieldString})
    VALUES ({$paramString})
";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($paramArray);
```

Comment: for the automatically generated query it doesn't make difference which placeholder type to use, whereas positional placeholders are less error prone, for example they will go all right if you have a space in the field name. In the end you have more complex code that is less convenient. I doubt it could be called a simplification.

Comment: I've just run into this same problem. One single placeholder and one single parameter value with a comma in it gives an error of a count mismatch. I tried quotations and everything else I can think of to no avail. I do need the value to be passed as it with the comma intact, without exploding it or anything else. Has there ever been a good solution to this?